# Adding a save button that saves statistics when exiting the app

Tags: python, tkinter

So i have coded a soccer player statistics application for my software development project, the application allows you to edit the player statistics of the players and also add and delete new players into the application. The thing I am struggling with is being able to add a "Save" button which saves the stats that have been edited when exiting the application. Thanks for your help in advance.

````
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from tkinter import *
import os
import re

#Designing window for registration

def register():
    global register_screen
    register_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    register_screen.title("Register")
    register_screen.geometry("300x250")
#Globalling variables
    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    global invLbl
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
 #Labels and entry fields for register screen
    invLbl = Label(register_screen, text="", fg="red", font=("calibri", 11))
    Label(register_screen, text="Please enter details below", bg="blue").pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    username_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Username * ")
    username_lable.pack()
    username_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.pack()
    password_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Password * ")
    password_lable.pack()
    password_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password, show='*')
    password_entry.pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="blue", command = register_user).pack()
    invLbl.pack()

#Designing window for login

def login():
    global login_screen
    login_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.geometry("300x250")
    Label(login_screen, text="Please enter details below to login").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    global username_login_entry
    global password_login_entry

    Label(login_screen, text="Username * ").pack()
    username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Password * ").pack()
    password_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password_verify, show= '*')
    password_login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command = login_verify).pack()

#Implementing event on register button

def register_user():    
    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    valid = True
    for char in username_info:
        if char.isdigit() == True:
            valid = False
            #If there is a for example a number iin the username, this error message will be printed.
            invLbl.config(text="Invalid Username")
    if username_info == '':
        valid = False
        #If the username is left blank, this error message will be printed.
        invLbl.config(text="Enter a Username")
    
    #Password Validation
    if len(password_info) <3 or len(password_info) > 16:
        valid = False
        invLbl.config(text="Ensure password is not less than 3 or greater than 16 digits.")
    
    if valid == True:
        file = open(username_info, "w")
        file.write(username_info + "\n")
        file.write(password_info)
        file.close()
        #Registration Success Message
        invLbl.config(text="Registration Success!", fg="green")
    
    
    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

#Implementing event on login button

def login_verify():
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_login_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_login_entry.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            login_sucess()


        else:
            password_not_recognised()

    else:
        user_not_found()

#Designing popup for login success

def login_sucess():
    global login_success_screen
    login_success_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    login_success_screen.title("Success")
    login_success_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(login_success_screen, text="Login Success").pack()
    Button(login_success_screen, text="OK", command=delete_login_success).pack()

#Designing popup for login invalid password

def password_not_recognised():
    global password_not_recog_screen
    password_not_recog_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    password_not_recog_screen.title("Success")
    password_not_recog_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(password_not_recog_screen, text="Invalid Password ").pack()
    Button(password_not_recog_screen, text="OK", command=delete_password_not_recognised).pack()

#Designing popup for user not found

def user_not_found():
    global user_not_found_screen
    user_not_found_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    user_not_found_screen.title("Success")
    user_not_found_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(user_not_found_screen, text="User Not Found").pack()
    Button(user_not_found_screen, text="OK", command=delete_user_not_found_screen).pack()

#Deleting popups

def delete_login_success():
    login_success_screen.destroy()
    next_main_screen()
    login_screen.destroy()

def delete_password_not_recognised():
    password_not_recog_screen.destroy()


def delete_user_not_found_screen():
    user_not_found_screen.destroy()


#Designing Main(first) window

def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Account Login")
    Label(text="Select Your Choice", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30", command = login).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30", command=register).pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()



KEYS = ("Matches Played", "Goals", "Assists", "YC", "RC")

#Creating a player and save into "stored_data"
def create_player(name, matches=0, goals=0, assists=0, yc=0, rc=0):
    global statistics
    global stats
    statistics = {}
    stats={} #Created for sorting.

    for key, val in zip(KEYS, (matches, goals, assists, yc, rc)):

        statistics[key] = tk.IntVar(value=val)
        stats[key]=val #=== set value as val for the key.
    side_things[name]=stats #=== Save it in dict
    stored_data[name] = statistics


def delete_player(name):
    #Clearing the frame, then rewriting it.

    stored_data.pop(name) #Removes from dictionary
    side_things.pop(name)
    for widget in table_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    tk.Label(text="Chelsea FC Player Statistics", font=(None, 15, 'bold'), fg="blue",).pack(pady=5)
    tk.Button(table_frame, text="Player Name",command=sort_name, font=font, anchor="w", width=20, fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")

    for col, key in enumerate(KEYS, 1):
        tk.Button(table_frame, text=key, font=font,command=lambda xk=key: sort_other(xk), width=12, fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=col)
    tk.Label(table_frame, font=font, anchor="w", fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=col+1, sticky="ew")

    for row, name in enumerate(stored_data, 1):
        add_player_row(table_frame, row, name)


#Edit player statistics function
def edit_player(parent, name):
    def change(var, delta):
        value = var.get() + delta
        if value >= 0:
            var.set(value)

    def create_form(parent, key, var):
        f = tk.Frame(parent, bd=1, relief="sunken")
        f.pack(side="left")
        tk.Label(f, text=key, width=12, fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
        tk.Button(f, text="-", command=lambda: change(var, -1)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        tk.Label(f, textvariable=var, width=3).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Button(f, text="+", command=lambda: change(var, +1)).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="ew")


    tp = tk.Toplevel(parent)
    tp.title("Edit Player Statistics")
    tk.Label(tp, text=name, font="Helvetica 14 bold").pack()
    frame = tk.Frame(tp)
    frame.pack()
    statistics = stored_data[name]
    stats=side_things[name]

    for col, (key, var) in enumerate(statistics.items(), 1):
        create_form(frame, key, var)
        stats[key]=var.get()

    tp.grab_set()
    tp.wait_window()
    for j,k in statistics.items():
        stats[j]=k.get() #==== Edit the values in side_dict's stata
def sort_name():
    #Sort by name

    from collections import OrderedDict
    order = OrderedDict(sorted(stored_data.items())) #Sort values in key pairs
    for widget in table_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    tk.Label(text="Chelsea FC Player Statistics", font=(None, 15, 'bold'), fg="blue",).pack(pady=5)
    tk.Button(table_frame, text="Player Name",command=sort_name, font=font, anchor="w", width=20, fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")

    for col, key in enumerate(KEYS, 1):
        tk.Button(table_frame, text=key, font=font,command=lambda xk=key: sort_other(xk), width=12, fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=col)
    tk.Label(table_frame, font=font, anchor="w", fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=col+1, sticky="ew")

    for row, name in enumerate(order, 1):
        add_player_row(table_frame, row, name)
def sort_other(name):
    #Sort by another values
    order=sorted(side_things.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][name], reverse=True) #== Sort the dict.
    print(order)
    for widget in table_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    tk.Label(text="Chelsea FC Player Statistics", font=(None, 15, 'bold'), fg="blue",).pack(pady=5)
    tk.Button(table_frame, text="Player Name",command=sort_name, font=font, anchor="w", width=20, fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
    for col, key in enumerate(KEYS, 1):
        tk.Button(table_frame, text=key, font=font,command=lambda xk=key: sort_other(xk), width=12, fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=col)
    tk.Label(table_frame, font=font, anchor="w", fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=col+1, sticky="ew")
    for row, name in enumerate(order, 1):
        print(name[0])
        add_player_row(table_frame, row, name[0])
#Show player statistics
def add_player_row(parent, row, name):
    tk.Label(parent, text=name, anchor="w").grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="ew")
    statistics = stored_data[name]
    for col, key in enumerate(KEYS, 1):
        tk.Label(parent, textvariable=statistics[key]).grid(row=row, column=col)
    tk.Button(parent, text="Edit", command=lambda: edit_player(root, name)).grid(row=row, column=col+1)
    tk.Button(parent, text="Delete", command=lambda: delete_player(name)).grid(row=row, column=col+2)


#Ask for new player name and create the player
def new_player(parent):
    # get player name
    name = askstring("New Player", "Player Name")
    if name:
        create_player(name)
        add_player_row(parent, len(stored_data), name)
#Next main screen
def next_main_screen():
    global root
    main_screen.withdraw()
    root=Toplevel()
    global stored_data
    stored_data = {}
    global side_things
    side_things ={}

    #Storing current player data
    #create_player
    create_player('Daniel Keelagher', 10, 4, 4, 0, 0)
    create_player('Joseph Keelagher', 10, 2, 2, 1, 0)
    create_player('Benjamin Miller', 10, 0, 0, 1, 0)
    create_player('Joran Terlato', 8, 1, 1, 3, 1)
    create_player('Arki Gantzos', 9, 3, 2, 0, 0)
    create_player('Billy Houndalas', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    create_player('Hayato Uematsu', 9, 2, 3, 0, 0)
    create_player('Mark Boccari', 10, 1, 1, 2, 0)
    create_player('Oliver Gibson', 7, 1, 2, 0, 0)
    create_player('Zaid Khaleqi', 9, 2, 0, 0, 0)
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",lambda: [root.destroy(),main_screen.destroy()])
    # Application title
    tk.Label(text="Chelsea FC Player Statistics", font=(None, 15, 'bold'), fg="blue",).pack(pady=5)

    #Frame showing player statistics
    global table_frame
    table_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    table_frame.pack()

    #Table Headings
    global font
    font="Helvetica 13 bold"
    tk.Button(table_frame, text="Player Name",command=sort_name, font=font, anchor="w", width=20, fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
    for col, key in enumerate(KEYS, 1):
        tk.Button(table_frame, text=key, font=font,command=lambda xk=key: sort_other(xk), width=12, fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=col)
    tk.Label(table_frame, font=font, anchor="w", fg="white", bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=col+1, sticky="ew")

    #Player statistics table
    for row, name in enumerate(stored_data, 1):
        add_player_row(table_frame, row, name)

    #Add new player button
    tk.Button(root, text="Add New Player", command=lambda: new_player(table_frame)).pack(pady=5)
    #Main loop of tkinter

    #Main block
main_account_screen()```
````

Comment: What have you tried so far on trying to add a `Save` function? SO is not a place for asking for code.

Comment: I tried many things, it didnt work. Please help

Comment: Please don't post so much code. Try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about how to save data to a file, we don't need all the widgets since reading and writing files don't care where the data comes from. If the question is how to pull data out of the widgets, we only need a few widgets to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Post what have you tried and state the problem you came across.

Comment: i tried to code it by using labels and then defining a function, it didn't work. :( help!

Comment: Try writing the stats in a text file so that it can be saved